# Cannot resolve IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry with polly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, polly

I have a web api which has all the correct references to polly

One of my services has a constructor with the constructor

```
public MyService(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry)
```

Unable to resolve service for type 'Polly.Registry.IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry`1[System.String]'

How can I fix this?  That information is not helpful at all

I am using the Polly packages below

```
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Distributed" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly.Contrib.DuplicateRequestCollapser" Version="0.2.1" />
```

Paul

Comment: What version of Polly are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly won't inherently make `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>` available to your dependency injection container, so unless you manually add it with its implementation being provided by the `PolicyRegistry` concrete type, it won't be available.

However, if you use the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly) package in ASP.NET Core with `IHttpClientFactory` then it will be added automatically by the [`AddPolicyRegistry()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyservicecollectionextensions.addpolicyregistry).

You will need to either add the extra package and then call that method, or manually register the dependency with your service collection, such as by doing:

```
services.AddSingleton<IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>, PolicyRegistry>();
```

Comment: Im not sure how to use the AddPolicyRegistry() method, i.e. what to put in my startup.cs for it

Comment: Here's a repo where I use it if you want to take a look, and that makes any more sense: https://github.com/martincostello/alexa-london-travel-site/blob/9759f4fabf55214078b433f11ddb2057ff46a371/src/LondonTravel.Site/Extensions/PollyServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L48

Comment: Thanks that still doesnt work I dont see that method.  I will have to go with the manual registration I guess